# How to create a tkinter label for every item in a list?

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I want tkinter to create a Label for every item in a list. Problem: this list can have various lengths cause it's based on user input.

I managed to create a variable for every item in the list. But how can I access each variable (assign `Label` and `var_name.grid()` ) if I don't know its name while writing the program?

```
keys = ["foo", "bar"]
count = 0

for key in keys:
    
    labelname = "label_w_" + str(key)
    globals()[labelname] = None

    # I can access the first variable created statically, but what about the others?
    label_w_foo = Label(window, text = key)
    label_w_foo.grid(row = count, column = 1)
    count += 1

window.update()
```

Comment: You can add the label to a list too

Comment: @Sujay yes, i can store its name, but i can then only recieve its name, not access the variable itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this answer the question?

```
from tkinter import *
window =Tk()
keys = ["foo", "bar"]
count = 0
labels=[]
def change_text():
    for j,l in enumerate(labels):
        l.config(text=str(keys[j])+str(j))
for key in keys:
    # I can access the first variable created statically, but what about the others?
    labels.append(Label(window,text=key))
    labels[count].grid(row = count, column = 1)
    count += 1
print(labels)
Button(window,text="Change Text",command=change_text).grid(row=count, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```